# Get Current month & year and Passing to API iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, json, api, swift3

I have a func in which i have to pass current month & year parameters to Fetch API in Swift 3.If i pass hardCode in parameters i am getting the son response but i am not able to do it with current month & year. Code :-

```
func raffleNumberGenerate(){
    let prs = [
        "month":currentMonth,
        "year" : currentYear,
        "raffle_result": "1" as String
    ]
    Service.StartWithoutLoading(prs as [String : AnyObject]?, onCompletion: { result in
        let jsonResponseSingle = result as? NSDictionary
        print(" JSON Response :- \(String(describing: jsonResponseSingle))"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you getting `currentMonth` and `currentYear`? Could be a formatting issue, where your hardcoded values are formatted correctly but your variable values are not.

Comment: For getting the results from this func i have to pass current month in e.g.. 10 and year = 2017 format @CodeNinja could u help me

Comment: Please show the code that sets the values of `currentMonth` and `currentYear`

Comment: i do not have any idea @CodeNinja

Comment: Well if you aren't setting these values then of course it isn't going to work. You need to give them a value, and Norman's answer will give you what you need.

Comment: could u post an answer as per my req.using above code @CodeNinja

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156038/discussion-between-codeninja-and-anuj).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have no values for `currentMonth` and `currentYear`, so you must make some.

```
func raffleNumberGenerate() {
    let date = Date() // gets current date
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let currentYear = calendar.component(.year, from: date) // gets current year (i.e. 2017)
    let currentMonth = calendar.component(.month, from: date) // gets current month (i.e. 10)

    let prs = [
        "month":currentMonth,
        "year" : currentYear,
        "raffle_result": "1" as String
    ]

    Service.StartWithoutLoading(prs as [String : AnyObject]?, onCompletion: { result in
        let jsonResponseSingle = result as? NSDictionary
        print(" JSON Response :- \(String(describing: jsonResponseSingle))"
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to do whatever you need to do with the JSON. I should note that `currentMonth` and `currentYear` are now of type `Int`, if you need them as Strings you can just convert by saying `String(currentMonth)` and `String(currentYear)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
let today = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"
let year = dateFormatter.string(from: today)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM"
let month = dateFormatter.string(from: today)
```

e.g. year = 2017 month = 10

per @maddy

```
var calendar = NSCalendar.current
let today = Date()
let desiredComponents = Set<Calendar.Component>([.month, .year])
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")!
let components = calendar.dateComponents(desiredComponents, from: today)
components.year
components.month
```

Comment: This is a very inefficient way to get the year and month from a date. Use DateComponents.

Comment: @anuj the code was cut directly from a functioning playground. Did you define currentMonth and currentYear with their values? e.g. let currentMonth = components.month? You might want to share your updated code.